# How to optimize the code with try/except block?

Tags: python, dictionary, refactoring

I have function like:

```
def get_nested_dicts(items: dict, *keys, default=None):
    for key in keys:
        try:
            items = items[key]
        except KeyError:
            return default
        else:
            if not isinstance(items, dict):
                break

    return items
```

The main idea is optimizing work with nested dictionaries, for example,
I have constraction like:

> dictionary = {'a': {'b': {'c': 10}}}

Output will be like:

```
print(get_nested_dicts(items, 'a', 'b', 'c')) # 10 
print(get_nested_dicts(items, 'a', 'c', 'b')) # None
print(get_nested_dicts(items, 'd', 'e', 'g')) # None
```

And want to optimize it more, make in more pythonic way. Are there some solutions to optimize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dict.get()`as follows:

```
def get_nested_dicts(items: dict, *keys, default=None):
    for key in keys:
        items = items.get(key, default)
        if not isinstance(items, dict):
            break

    return items
```

**Input**

```
dictionary = {'a': {'b': {'c': 10}}}

print(get_nested_dicts(dictionary, 'a', 'b', 'c')) 
print(get_nested_dicts(dictionary, 'a', 'c', 'b')) 
print(get_nested_dicts(dictionary, 'd', 'e', 'g'))
```

**Output**

```
10
None
None
```

Here `get()` takes two arguments the key and the default value to return. Here it returns the value corresponding to the key if key is present in the dictionary else `None` is returned.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I think better to handle the exception

Comment: I understand. It was my mistake. Thanks ))

Comment: @try_to_code I don't understand your requirement.

Comment: Now understand, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, .get() function will help you optimize this a little bit.

```
def get_nested_dicts(items: dict, *keys, default=None):
    for key in keys:
        items = items.get(key, default)
        if not isinstance(items, dict): break
    return items
```

Another pythonic way is to use the wildcard - 'reduce'.

```
from functools import reduce

def get_nested_dicts(items: dict, *keys, default=None):
    return reduce(lambda v, k: v.get(k, default) if v else default, keys, items)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, helpful solution!